# Hash algorithm used by HashAttribute processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to know the specific hash algorithm used by the HashAttribute processor in Nifi.

Answer (score 2):

all matched attribute names and values ( or value parts if group present  ) are joined into into one string and the result is hashed with **MD5** algorithm

here is the source:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/HashAttribute.java#L225

the official HashAttribute documentation:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HashAttribute/